# Why getCanonicalPath throws checked exception while getAbsolutePath does not?

Tags: java, io

I know the differences between the two by reading some related text. But I am curious that why `getCanonicalPath()` throws checked exception while `getAbsolutePath()` does not throw any?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ***But I am curious that why `getCanonicalPath()` throws checked exception while `getAbsolutePath()` does not throw any?***

It says why in [the documentation for `getCanonicalPath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29):

> *`IOException` - If an I/O error occurs, which is possible because **the construction of the canonical pathname may require filesystem queries***